# Google Map Hybrid and Aerial tiles missing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, tiles, missing-data

I am using google map api. I am having an issue with Google base map. When i load Google hybrid or aerial, it gives me following result.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u51hegt7hu03gz9/Untitled.png?dl=0

Some tiles are missing on the map.

Missing tiles: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vlp86xf4iote32/Untitled2.png?dl=0

My code is:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(mapA, 'maptypeid_changed', function () {
        var mapTypeId = mapA.getMapTypeId();
        if (mapTypeId != "basemap")
            mapTileSource = [];
        if (mapTypeId == google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID) {
            mapTileSource.push("http://khm1.google.com/kh/v=134&x={0}&y={1}&z={2}&s=Gal");
            mapTileSource.push("http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=h@177290279&hl=en&x={0}&y={1}&z={2}&s=Gal");
        }
        else if (mapTypeId == google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP) {
            mapTileSource.push("http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@113&hl=hu&x={0}&y={1}&z={2}&s=Gal");
        }
        else if (mapTypeId == google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE) {
            mapTileSource.push("http://khm1.google.com/kh/v=134&x={0}&y={1}&z={2}&s=Gal");
        }
        else if (mapTypeId == google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN) {
            mapTileSource.push("http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=t@131,r@176163100&hl=en&x={0}&y={1}&z={2}&s=Gal");
        }
    });
```

Some tiles are missing on the view.

I have tried this:

```js
    function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
        debugger;
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
    }
    CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
        var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = coord;
        div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
        div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
        div.style.fontSize = '10';
        div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
        div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
        return div;
    };
    mapA.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
```

And i have also tried this:

```js
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapA, 'tilesloaded', function() {
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapA, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(mapA, 'resize');
            });
});
```

But they did not work for me.

Can anyone please tell me the way to load all the tiles on the map?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set higher version (the number after m@ or h@ etc.) and use url directly in web broswer (check if tile in this version exists)

http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@901000000&hl=en&x=4&y=10&z=5&s=Ga

or check your cache layer (if you use)

In my option for googleSatellite :

**get error** - http://khm0.google.com/kh/v=149&hl=en&x=18&y=9&z=5&s=Galileo

******* **ok** - http://khm0.google.com/kh/v=165&hl=en&x=18&y=9&z=5&s=Galileo

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of mapbox with google maps hybrid satellite view: https://github.com/SnakeO/mapbox-with-google-maps-hybrid-tiles